# Unable to convert MobiletNet_v1 from Pytorch

Tags: python

When I try to run my code for varitionnal auto-encoder I get this error :

```
test_and_train.py:None (test_and_train.py)
test_and_train.py:102: in <module>
    model_net = VoxceptionNet(n_classes=40).to(device)
..\..\..\Anaconda3\envs\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:381: in to
    return self._apply(convert)
..\..\..\Anaconda3\envs\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:187: in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
..\..\..\Anaconda3\envs\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:193: in _apply
    param.data = fn(param.data)
..\..\..\Anaconda3\envs\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:379: in convert
    return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() else None, non_blocking)
E   RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device ordinal
```

Comment: Please provide your code for better help.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting that error if the pre-trained model is trained on a different number of Cuda devices.

you can refere to this [issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/15848) on github it might help you.

Comment: is there anyway i can send it to you ? so you can check it ?

Comment: @M.R. i didn't guess the code , it is a common problem in loading models in pytorch.

Comment: @AchrafFakhfakh put your code in your question and i'll take a look

Comment: @KaitoEinstein i will send you the full project , so can you please give me your email ?

Comment: ssnitra20@gmail.com